# Why can't cmake find build program?

Tags: c, cmake, doxygen

I'm trying to set up Doxygen to create a documentation for my C project exam, as it is required by my professor. Btw, I'm facing many problems. I read that I need to download this cmake program to make doxygen work. So I did it and wrote the first three commands for the cmd showed on doxygen.nl:

```
cd doxygen-$VERSION
mkdir build
cd build
```

right after this I need to write

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ..
```

and that's when the problems begin, as I get this error:

```
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Unix Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/user_name/doxygen/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: On which platform are you working , which version of doxygen do you try to compile, Which compiler do you have installed?

Comment: @albert I'm working on Windows 11, Doxygen version is 1.9.3 (the latest). As for the compiler I have no idea

Comment: it should be gcc 5.1.0, that's what is says when i open codeblocks

Comment: You are trying to use the *nix workflow on a Windows system. Why don't you download the doxygen executable for windows and install this one (see: https://www.doxygen.nl/download.html#srcbin)?

Comment: yes, that was it...i'm the noobest of noobs. Thank you

Comment: Note that the version you use in CodeBlocks (gcc 5.1.0 is also quite old April 22, 2015, see https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html), probably in need of some update as well...

Comment: I assume the professor is using Linux for the course, so probably the safest route would be to get a VM running Ubuntu 18 or setup WSL to do this. That way you're able to use the exact same programs your professor is using minimizing the risk of something working for you locally, but not on the system the professor uses for evaluation. Visual Studio Code has a decent CMake/WSL integration btw... If for some reason you're only interested in running doxygen from cmake, you could simply go with the Visual Studio generator; assuming you've got doxygen installed you should be able to build the docs